# EE still thinks I am logged in after logging out

Tags: login, logout

I have page where the content depends on whether you are logged in or not. This is the tag that I used to check

```
{if logged_out}
   ...
{if:else}
  ...
{/if}
```

However, even if I am logged out, I always get to the second part which is meant for logged in users.

I have cleared the cache from EE and the cookies from my browser. But it did not help.

Which parts of EE should I be looking for to solve this problem?

**Some more information**

- I am using the url below to log out

  `{redirect="?ACT=16&amp;return=/sign-out/"}`
- I am using Safecracker Registration. All the kinks with upgrading to 2.7.1 have been worked out.

**UPDATE:**

I outputted some variables and I got this

```
logged_in_member_id: 1
logged_in_group_id: 1
logged_in_group_description:
logged_in_username:
logged_in_screen_name:
logged_in_email:
```

**Another UPDATE:**

I have Template A and Template B.

Template A embeds Template B.

I added code to show logged_in status in both Templates

```
<div>
    {if logged_in}
        LOGGED IN
    {/if}

    {if logged_out}
        LOGGED OUT
    {/if}
</div>
```

The problem is that in Template A, logged_in is FALSE

but in Template B, logged_in is TRUE

This is weird. So {logged_in} can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{redirect="{site_url}?ACT=16&return=/sign-out/"}
```

The & will probably be treated as part of the string instead of the divider between query strings.

Also try (just to keep it simple):

```
{redirect="{site_url}?ACT=16"}
```

Assuming the logout is working and it's the conditional that's at fault, try this conditional instead:

```
{if logged_out}
   ...
{/if}
{if logged_in}
  ...
{/if}
```

Comment: The redirect is a great option, but I would also make the redirect create a login. You could also make the content secure and hidden if member_group == whatever the membergroup needs to be. That works good to.

Comment: I tried the conditional but they still always evalute to logged_in

Comment: No {logged_in} can't be changed between embeds, so if that's occurring, something else is incorrect - you'd need to provide your full template code for the template that is incorrectly reporting logged in (or out). Also have you tried access Template B directly (without going through Template A)?

Answer (score 0):

It's rather strange you're getting different results on different templates.

The overall problem though must have something to do with the parse order, since the {if:else} advanced conditional never really worked for me in EE when applied to a logged_in conditional. You have to consider that an "advanced" conditional is evaluated much later in the parsing order, so it might apply to your situation if it's included inside some `{exp}` tags.

What version do you have installed? I read that some new parsing rules have been introduced with the latest EE releases. If you have the possibility to update I would do so, otherwise I would stick with:

```
{if logged_out}
   //DO SOMETHING
{/if}
{if logged_in}
  //DO SOMETHING ELSE
{/if}
```

You can also give a try to this module: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee
or this one: https://github.com/croxton/ifElse
I haven't tested them yet, but apparently they make the advanced conditionals parse earlier in EE templates. Share the results if you happen to try that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using EE 2.7.2. Btw, if you look at my example above, I did not use `{if:else}` since I too have problems with it in the past.

Comment: It can't return two different statuses in two different templates. Can you post more of your code from the templates?